# Performance of different database design(Google Places API)

Tags: mysql, database, performance, google-places-api, query-performance

I'm wondering which database design will be more efficient. Before that, my scenario is I want to do a search using google places api. The API will return me city, states, country and I have listings that having relationship with these data.

It will have many to many between Listing and Location

First Attempt:

```
Location Table

-id

-city

-states

-country
```

Eg:

```
City |  States | Country

A  |  B  | C

D  |  B  | C

E  |  F  | G
```

When I search through the google API and returning me response, I will check the table and search through the city ,states, and country columns. Therefore, this 3 columns will be indexed.

Second Attempt:

```
Location Table

-id

-parent_id

-name
```

So, this will be like hierarchy. So basically if I try to search through the listing, if it is on Country, i will have to query for the children(States) and then from the child, I need to query again to get the specific children(City) to get all the listing which I think will consist more query involved?

So, when the data grows, what is the best database design for searching through the tables? Any suggestion database design when using Google Places API?

Comment: Any chance you could provide a link to the specific API call you are making?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete @SteveChambers following this as well http://blog.pamelafox.org/2012/08/using-maps-api-autocomplete-for-user.html

Comment: Can you describe the queries that you want to run on your data?

Comment: Hmm, query will be to get a specific location listing. Example: when i query a country location, it should return all states and cities listings as well.

Comment: what is the GoogleAPI result look like, One Row with single Column, One Row With 3 Column, More than One Row With Single column, More Than One Row with 3 Columns. depending on this result type either your search query will be doing a SET BASED operation or a Search for Specific values in at most 3 column in Location table.

Answer (score 1):

I've this problem before and try many options, the one that worked best for me was to make 3 tables: Cities, zones and countries.

```
countries [id,name]
zones [id,country_id,name]
cities[id,country_id,zone_id,name]
```

First of all you query the Countries table (only 190 rows, very fast)

```
SELECT id FROM countries WHERE name LIKE 'Spain';
```

After that you query the zone tables using the country_id to restrict the number of string compared.

```
SELECT id FROM zones WHERE country_id = {Your country id} AND name LIKE 'Leon';
```

Finally you query the city

```
SELECT name FROM cities WHERE country_id = {Your country id} AND zone_id = {Your zone id} AND name LIKE 'Villabúrbula';
```

Comment: Hi, thanks look nice..how about if my searching for location tag, i think it have to search through 3 tables?

Comment: In case you have to search a location without knowing the level, you could have another table with tags that look like tag,location_id,location_type. It allow you to have multiple names for the same location (for example many languages)

Answer (score 1):

How do you search through the table? Do you get country, city and state from the API and just look for the listings? Please clearify your question a bit.

Since the overall number of cities and towns is quite limited (around 30K in USA?), I very simply would combine

Location Table

```
-id
-city
-states
-country
```

with an `index (country, states, city)` and with mysql query cache:

```
select SQL_CACHE group_concat(id) from location where country={country} and states={states} and city={city}
```

Comment: since it will be a travel site, it will involve a lot of country and city i guess. ya, will get it from google places api

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you can go ahead with your data model and try optimizing your data using mainly indexes, as you know, the database querying performance optimization is not restricted to indexes, there's even companies that employs engineers exclusively for optimization tasks of their databases.
for the indexes it depends on your sql queries, so here's a diagram how to choose your indexes :

[image]

you can find the original post [here](http://www.toptal.com/sql/sql-database-tuning-for-developers), it provides some good tips for SQL performance optimization and best practices on querying databases, since it is dificult to mention all the tricks of optimization, I'll suggest for you this [link](http://web.synametrics.com/top10performancetips.htm).

Answer (score 0):

If you are querying google places API you want to look at optimising the places call.  For example, restrict the call to the country you're interested in

```
For US
place/autocomplete/json?input=%@&components=country:us
For UK
place/autocomplete/json?input=%@&components=country:gb
```

For my mobile app, the call to google places and parsing the return is a much bigger hit than querying and display of the cached data (which I hold in an NSDictionary - for an iOS app).

Answer (score 0):

My answer is based on writing a benchmark for different types of schemas, reading other Stack Overflow answers and my experience with databases. I came to the following conclusions:

1. The speed of execution does not differ a lot so you should not choose the database schema based on    performance. One my home notebook all queries executed in less than 70 milliseconds for 5% of all cities in the World.
2. The queries tend to increase in complexity with more tables, though they show the same data.
3. More tables generally allow the database to be more flexible to future changes.
4. More tables usually make the data structure clearer to understand.

I currently understand your problem this way:

Listings can have a very strange relationship to three types of location (country, state, city). Listings can be related to country, or to state, or to city. Listings can also have many relations to locations. For example, one listing can have two states and two cities. Countries, states and cities can have multiple listings.

If we normalize the database schema we get the following structure:

- Listings [id,listing_location_id,name]
- Listings_Locations [id,listing_id, location_id]
- Locations [id, country_id, state_id, city_id] depending on what location is used only the corresponding field is assigned, e.g. [1,1,null,null]
- Countries [id,name]
- States [id,country_id,name]
- Cities[id,country_id,state_id,name]

In my opinion the structure is too complicated. 6 tables instead of one is too much. In my benchmark I created queries with 4 tables (because there I solved a simpler task). I tried to think just of one case where one table will not allow changes in the future and I could not find any.

Therefore, though I generally choose a clearer database design perhaps in this particular case you should just use one table.

I suppose the total number of cities is about 1 million as USA has 40 thousands zip codes and India has
150 thousand zip codes. I have 50 thousand cities in my benchmark so I have more cities then there are cities in the USA. With query execution time of 50-70 ms per query on my home notebook you do not have any problems with performance.

### The benchmark

I wrote a benchmark with three schemas but only with one-to-many relationship between Listings and Cities. I used Microsoft SQL Server LocalDb and C#:

1: Only one table for all relationships

Table Var1:[id,city,state,country,name] - Table for Listings with listing name

2: Four tables

- Countries [id,name]
- States [id,country_id,name]
- Cities[id,country_id,state_id,name]
- Listings [id,country_id,state_id,city_id,name]

3: Four tables with simpler Listings table

- Countries [id,name]
- States [id,country_id,name]
- Cities[id,country_id,state_id,name]
- Listings [id,city_id,name]

I populated the tables with the same randomly generated data (93312 listings: 36 countries, 36 state for each country, 36 cities for each state, 2 listings for each city)

I made 1000 queries for cities, 1000 queries for states and 1000 queries for countries.

The results are:

3 min 01 sec for 3000 queries (60 milliseconds per query) when using one table.

2 min 35 sec for 3000 queries (52 milliseconds per query) when using three tables with listings table having more columns.

3 min 30 sec for 3000 queries (70 milliseconds per query) when using three tables with listings table having less columns.

The output of my program:

```
Populating tables with 93312 listings
Tables populated in 00:08:46.5106145 time
Populating lists to search
Lists to search populated in 00:00:00.0009959 time
Executing 1000 database queries with a single table
Select * FROM Var1 WHERE country=MRWLULIQDN
Select * FROM Var1 WHERE state=VCASEMPJMR
Select * FROM Var1 WHERE city=WHELRRTQGN
Queries executed in 00:03:01.2917528 time
Executing 1000 database queries with 3 tables
Select ci.id as Id, co.name as Country,st.name as State,ci.name as City, li.name
 as Name FROM Var2_Countries AS co INNER JOIN Var2_States AS st on co.Id=st.Coun
try_id INNER JOIN Var2_Cities AS ci on ci.Country_id = co.Id AND ci.State_id = s
t.Id INNER JOIN Var2_Listings AS li on ci.Id=li.City_id WHERE co.name=MRWLULIQDN

Select ci.id as Id, co.name as Country,st.name as State,ci.name as City, li.name
 as Name FROM Var2_Countries AS co INNER JOIN Var2_States AS st on co.Id=st.Coun
try_id INNER JOIN Var2_Cities AS ci on ci.Country_id = co.Id AND ci.State_id = s
t.Id INNER JOIN Var2_Listings AS li on ci.Id=li.City_id WHERE st.name=VCASEMPJMR

Select ci.id as Id, co.name as Country,st.name as State,ci.name as City, li.name
 as Name FROM Var2_Countries AS co INNER JOIN Var2_States AS st on co.Id=st.Coun
try_id INNER JOIN Var2_Cities AS ci on ci.Country_id = co.Id AND ci.State_id = s
t.Id INNER JOIN Var2_Listings AS li on ci.Id=li.City_id WHERE ci.name=WHELRRTQGN

Queries executed in 00:02:35.7975130 time
Executing 1000 database queries with 3 tables and only 3 columns in listings
Select ci.id as Id, co.name as Country,st.name as State,ci.name as City, li.name
 as Name FROM Var2_Countries AS co INNER JOIN Var2_States AS st on co.Id=st.Coun
try_id INNER JOIN Var2_Cities AS ci on ci.Country_id = co.Id AND ci.State_id = s
t.Id INNER JOIN Var3_Listings AS li on ci.Id=li.City_id WHERE co.name=MRWLULIQDN

Select ci.id as Id, co.name as Country,st.name as State,ci.name as City, li.name
 as Name FROM Var2_Countries AS co INNER JOIN Var2_States AS st on co.Id=st.Coun
try_id INNER JOIN Var2_Cities AS ci on ci.Country_id = co.Id AND ci.State_id = s
t.Id INNER JOIN Var3_Listings AS li on ci.Id=li.City_id WHERE st.name=VCASEMPJMR

Select ci.id as Id, co.name as Country,st.name as State,ci.name as City, li.name
 as Name FROM Var2_Countries AS co INNER JOIN Var2_States AS st on co.Id=st.Coun
try_id INNER JOIN Var2_Cities AS ci on ci.Country_id = co.Id AND ci.State_id = s
t.Id INNER JOIN Var3_Listings AS li on ci.Id=li.City_id WHERE ci.name=WHELRRTQGN

Queries executed in 00:03:30.0670642 time
```

The table schemas:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Var1] (
    [Id]      INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [City]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [State]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Country] NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Name]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Var2_Cities] (
    [Id]         INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Country_id] INT            NOT NULL,
    [State_id]   INT            NOT NULL,
    [name]       NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Var2_Countries] (
    [Id]   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [name] NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Var2_States] (
    [Id]         INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Country_id] INT            NOT NULL,
    [name]       NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Var2_Listings] (
    [Id]         INT        IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Country_id] INT        NOT NULL,
    [State_id]   INT        NOT NULL,
    [City_id]    INT        NOT NULL,
    [Name]       NCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Var3_Listings] (
    [Id]      INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [City_id] INT            NOT NULL,
    [Name]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

The code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Transactions;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            var nol = 50000; //number of locations
            var noQueries = 1000; //number of queries
            var locations = new List<Var1>();
            var listings = new List<Var2_Listings>();
            var rnd = new Random();
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            string sql;
            var context = new DBEntities();

            var objCtx = ((System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
            objCtx.ExecuteStoreCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE [Var1]");
            objCtx.ExecuteStoreCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE [Var2_Cities]");
            objCtx.ExecuteStoreCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE [Var2_States]");
            objCtx.ExecuteStoreCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE [Var2_Countries]");
            objCtx.ExecuteStoreCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE [Var2_Listings]");

            context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

            Console.WriteLine("Populating tables with {0} listings", Math.Pow(Math.Floor(Math.Pow(nol, 1.0 / 3)),3)*2);
            sw.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Total no. of countries:{0}", Math.Floor(Math.Pow(nol, 1.0 / 3)));

            using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Math.Pow(nol, 1.0 / 3); i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Country no.{0}", i);
                    var country = RandomString(10);
                    //2
                    var countryEntity = new Var2_Countries();
                    countryEntity.name = country;
                    context.Var2_Countries.Add(countryEntity);


                }
                context.SaveChanges();
                scope.Complete();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Countries populated");

            int i1=0;
            var Countries = context.Var2_Countries.ToList();
            using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
            {
                foreach (var country in Countries)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Country no.{0}", i1);
                    //2
                    context.SaveChanges();

                    i1++;
                    for (int j = 0; j < Math.Pow(nol, 1.0 / 3); j++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("State no.{0}", j);
                        var state = RandomString(10);
                        //2
                        var stateEntity = new Var2_States();
                        stateEntity.name = state;
                        stateEntity.Country_id = country.Id;
                        context.Var2_States.Add(stateEntity);



                    }
                }
                context.SaveChanges();
                scope.Complete();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("States populated");


            i1++;
            int j1=0;
            var States = context.Var2_States.ToList();
            //var sw1 = new Stopwatch();
            //var sw2 = new Stopwatch();
            //var sw3 = new Stopwatch();
            //var sw4 = new Stopwatch();
            //sw1.Start();
            foreach (var state in States)
            {


                if (j1 % 500 == 0)
                {
                    context.SaveChanges();
                    context.Dispose();
                    context = new DBEntities();
                    context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
                    Console.WriteLine("State no.{0}", j1);
                }
                j1++;
                for (int k = 0; k < Math.Pow(nol, 1.0 / 3); k++)
                {

                    //sw2.Start();
                    var city = RandomString(10);
                    //sw2.Stop();

                    //2
                    //sw3.Start();
                    var cityEntity = new Var2_Cities();
                    cityEntity.name = city;
                    cityEntity.State_id = state.Id;
                    cityEntity.Country_id = state.Country_id;
                    //sw3.Stop();
                    //sw4.Start();
                    context.Var2_Cities.Add(cityEntity);
                    //sw4.Stop();
                }
            }
            //Console.WriteLine(sw1.Elapsed);
            //Console.WriteLine(sw2.Elapsed);
            //Console.WriteLine(sw3.Elapsed);
            //Console.WriteLine(sw4.Elapsed);


            context.Dispose();
            context = new DBEntities();
            context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
            Console.WriteLine("Cities populated");
            i1 = 0;
            int k1=0;
            var Cities = context.Var2_Cities.ToList();
            foreach (var city in Cities)
            {
                if (k1 % 2000 == 0)
                {
                    context.SaveChanges();
                    context.Dispose();
                    context = new DBEntities();
                    context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
                    Console.WriteLine("City no.{0}", k1);
                }

                k1++;
                for (int l = 0; l < 2; l++)
                {
                    var listingName = RandomString(10);
                    //1
                    var location = new Var1();
                    location.City = city.name;
                    location.State = States.First(x => x.Id == city.State_id).name;
                    location.Country = Countries.First(x => x.Id == city.Country_id).name;
                    location.Name = listingName;
                    locations.Add(location);
                    context.Var1.Add(location);

                    //2
                    var listingEntity = new Var2_Listings();
                    listingEntity.City_id = city.Id;
                    listingEntity.State_id = city.State_id;
                    listingEntity.Country_id = city.Country_id;
                    listingEntity.Name = listingName;
                    context.Var2_Listings.Add(listingEntity);
                    listings.Add(listingEntity);

                    //3
                    var listing2Entity = new Var3_Listings();
                    listing2Entity.City_id = city.Id;
                    listing2Entity.Name = listingName;
                    context.Var3_Listings.Add(listing2Entity);
                }
            }

            context.SaveChanges();
            context.Dispose();
            context = new DBEntities();
            context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

            Console.WriteLine("Listings populated");

            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Tables populated in {0} time", sw.Elapsed);





            Console.WriteLine("Populating lists to search");
            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();
            var listOfCoutriesToSearch = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < noQueries; i++)
            {
                var r = rnd.Next(locations.Count);
                listOfCoutriesToSearch.Add(locations[r].Country);
            }

            var listOfStatesToSearch = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < noQueries; i++)
            {
                var r = rnd.Next(locations.Count);
                listOfStatesToSearch.Add(locations[r].State);
            }

            var listOfCitiesToSearch = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < noQueries; i++)
            {
                var r = rnd.Next(locations.Count);
                listOfCitiesToSearch.Add(locations[r].City);
            }

            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Lists to search populated in {0} time", sw.Elapsed);

            Console.WriteLine("Executing {0} database queries with a single table", noQueries);
            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();

            int query_i = 0;
            int querytype_i = 0;
            foreach (string country in listOfCoutriesToSearch)
            {
                sql = "Select * FROM Var1 WHERE country={0}";
                List<Var1> result = context.Var1.SqlQuery(sql, country).ToList();
                query_i++;

                if (query_i % 5000 == 0)
                    Console.WriteLine("Executed {0} queries", query_i);
                querytype_i++;
                if (querytype_i == 1)
                    Console.WriteLine(sql, country);
            }
            querytype_i = 0;
            foreach (string state in listOfStatesToSearch)
            {
                sql = "Select * FROM Var1 WHERE state={0}";
                List<Var1> result = context.Var1.SqlQuery(sql, state).ToList();
                query_i++;
                if (query_i % 5000 == 0)
                    Console.WriteLine("Executed {0} queries", query_i);
                querytype_i++;
                if (querytype_i == 1)
                    Console.WriteLine(sql, state);
            }
            querytype_i = 0;
            foreach (string city in listOfCitiesToSearch)
            {
                sql = "Select * FROM Var1 WHERE city={0}";
                List<Var1> result = context.Var1.SqlQuery(sql, city).ToList();
                query_i++;
                if (query_i % 5000 == 0)
                    Console.WriteLine("Executed {0} queries", query_i);

                querytype_i++;
                if (querytype_i == 1)
                    Console.WriteLine(sql, city);
            }


            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Queries executed in {0} time", sw.Elapsed);

            Console.WriteLine("Executing {0} database queries with 3 tables", noQueries);
            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();

            query_i = 0;
            querytype_i = 0;
            foreach (string country in listOfCoutriesToSearch)
            {
                sql = "Select ci.id as Id, co.name as Country,st.name as State,ci.name as City, li.name as Name "+
                        "FROM Var2_Countries AS co " +
                        "INNER JOIN Var2_States AS st on co.Id=st.Country_id " +
                        "INNER JOIN Var2_Cities AS ci on ci.Country_id = co.Id AND ci.State_id = st.Id " +
                        "INNER JOIN Var2_Listings AS li on ci.Id=li.City_id " +
                        "WHERE co.name={0}";
                List<Var1> result = context.Var1.SqlQuery(sql, country).ToList();
                query_i++;
                if (query_i % 5000 == 0)
                    Console.WriteLine("Executed {0} queries", query_i);
                querytype_i++;
                if (querytype_i == 1)
                    Console.WriteLine(sql, country);
            }
            querytype_i = 0;
            foreach (string state in listOfStatesToSearch)
            {
                sql = "Select ci.id as Id, co.name as Country,st.name as State,ci.name as City, li.name as Name " +
                        "FROM Var2_Countries AS co " +
                        "INNER JOIN Var2_States AS st on co.Id=st.Country_id " +
                        "INNER JOIN Var2_Cities AS ci on ci.Country_id = co.Id AND ci.State_id = st.Id " +
                        "INNER JOIN Var2_Listings AS li on ci.Id=li.City_id " +
                        "WHERE st.name={0}";
                List<Var1> result = context.Var1.SqlQuery(sql, state).ToList();
                query_i++;
                if (query_i % 5000 == 0)
                    Console.WriteLine("Executed {0} queries", query_i);
                querytype_i++;
                if (querytype_i == 1)
                    Console.WriteLine(sql, state);
            }
            querytype_i = 0;
            foreach (string city in listOfCitiesToSearch)
            {
                sql = "Select ci.id as Id, co.name as Country,st.name as State,ci.name as City, li.name as Name " +
                        "FROM Var2_Countries AS co " +
                        "INNER JOIN Var2_States AS st on co.Id=st.Country_id " +
                        "INNER JOIN Var2_Cities AS ci on ci.Country_id = co.Id AND ci.State_id = st.Id " +
                        "INNER JOIN Var2_Listings AS li on ci.Id=li.City_id " +
                        "WHERE ci.name={0}";
                List<Var1> result = context.Var1.SqlQuery(sql, city).ToList();
                query_i++;
                if (query_i % 5000 == 0)
                    Console.WriteLine("Executed {0} queries", query_i);
                querytype_i++;
                if (querytype_i == 1)
                    Console.WriteLine(sql, city);

            }


            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Queries executed in {0} time", sw.Elapsed);

            Console.WriteLine("Executing {0} database queries with 3 tables and only 3 columns in listings", noQueries);
            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();

            query_i = 0;
            querytype_i = 0;
            foreach (string country in listOfCoutriesToSearch)
            {
                sql = "Select ci.id as Id, co.name as Country,st.name as State,ci.name as City, li.name as Name " +
                        "FROM Var2_Countries AS co " +
                        "INNER JOIN Var2_States AS st on co.Id=st.Country_id " +
                        "INNER JOIN Var2_Cities AS ci on ci.Country_id = co.Id AND ci.State_id = st.Id " +
                        "INNER JOIN Var3_Listings AS li on ci.Id=li.City_id " +
                        "WHERE co.name={0}";
                List<Var1> result = context.Var1.SqlQuery(sql, country).ToList();
                query_i++;
                if (query_i % 5000 == 0)
                    Console.WriteLine("Executed {0} queries", query_i);
                querytype_i++;
                if (querytype_i == 1)
                    Console.WriteLine(sql, country);
            }
            querytype_i = 0;
            foreach (string state in listOfStatesToSearch)
            {
                sql = "Select ci.id as Id, co.name as Country,st.name as State,ci.name as City, li.name as Name " +
                        "FROM Var2_Countries AS co " +
                        "INNER JOIN Var2_States AS st on co.Id=st.Country_id " +
                        "INNER JOIN Var2_Cities AS ci on ci.Country_id = co.Id AND ci.State_id = st.Id " +
                        "INNER JOIN Var3_Listings AS li on ci.Id=li.City_id " +
                        "WHERE st.name={0}";
                List<Var1> result = context.Var1.SqlQuery(sql, state).ToList();
                query_i++;
                if (query_i % 5000 == 0)
                    Console.WriteLine("Executed {0} queries", query_i);
                querytype_i++;
                if (querytype_i == 1)
                    Console.WriteLine(sql, state);
            }
            querytype_i = 0;
            foreach (string city in listOfCitiesToSearch)
            {
                sql = "Select ci.id as Id, co.name as Country,st.name as State,ci.name as City, li.name as Name " +
                        "FROM Var2_Countries AS co " +
                        "INNER JOIN Var2_States AS st on co.Id=st.Country_id " +
                        "INNER JOIN Var2_Cities AS ci on ci.Country_id = co.Id AND ci.State_id = st.Id " +
                        "INNER JOIN Var3_Listings AS li on ci.Id=li.City_id " +
                        "WHERE ci.name={0}";
                List<Var1> result = context.Var1.SqlQuery(sql, city).ToList();
                query_i++;
                if (query_i % 5000 == 0)
                    Console.WriteLine("Executed {0} queries", query_i);
                querytype_i++;
                if (querytype_i == 1)
                    Console.WriteLine(sql, city);

            }


            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Queries executed in {0} time", sw.Elapsed);


            Console.WriteLine("");
            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();

            //var objCtx = ((System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
            //objCtx.ExecuteStoreCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE [Var1]");
            //objCtx.ExecuteStoreCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE [Var2_Cities]");
            //objCtx.ExecuteStoreCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE [Var2_States]");
            //objCtx.ExecuteStoreCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE [Var2_Countries]");
            //objCtx.ExecuteStoreCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE [Var2_Listings]");

            Console.WriteLine("Program stopped");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static Random random = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);//thanks to McAden
        private static string RandomString(int size)
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            char ch;
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                ch = Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(26 * random.NextDouble() + 65)));
                builder.Append(ch);
            }

            return builder.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can change the benchmark to add other SQL queries.

Comment: hi @keiv.fly , looks acceptable, how about if I queries listings under a country, says India. So, it should retrieve all the listings under the country, states and cities. If one table, I just scan through the table for column 'India' which is country. If 3 tables, i should go through 3 different table...do it affect performance?

Comment: My query in the first table "Select * FROM Var1 WHERE country=PYSOOTSCJY" selects 441 rows in table Var1 with all the states and the cities. And in the second schema "Select ci.id as Id, co.name as Country,st.name as State,ci.name as City FROM Var
2_Countries AS co INNER JOIN Var2_States AS st on co.Id=st.Country_id INNER JOIN
 Var2_Cities AS ci on ci.Country_id = co.Id AND ci.State_id = st.Id WHERE co.nam
e=PYSOOTSCJY" also selects the same 441 cities with 21 states. So the performance is a little better with multiple tables.

Comment: I actually do not understand the question. If you search for only listins in one country and you have three tables then you find an index for the country in the country table - it is almost instant and then you look for all the listings with that country_id in the  table with listings, country_id, state_id, city_id.

Comment: But this way you would have to write the data about state_id and country_id twice - in the table with cities and in the table with listings. This is better for search performance, but not that good for inserting data and you can have the problem that the data in cities and in listings can differ due to an error in code.

Comment: I changed the answer and added a schema with listings table I would recommend

Comment: I added additional reasons for choosing a database schema, changed my opinion on the problem and changed the code to include listings with relationship one-to-many to cities. Not Many-to-many to any location, but still better.